# Junit method testing conditions

Tags: java, junit4

Suppose i have this java method :

```
boolean sample(){
  boolean returne = false;
  if( (a>b || b>c) && d>e ){
    returne = true;
  }
 return returne;
}
```

To be sure i have unit tested well my method, should i include all those scenarios in my unit tests methods :

- Test where a>b or b>c and d>e
- Test where a=b or b=c and d=e
- Test where a

  Test where a>b or b=c and d>e

  .... and going with all the possibilities...

Comment: If you use an IDE, they provide basic code coverage tools which tell you how much of your code is tested well, so you can ask it to run your unit tests with code coverage and then add tests which cover missing scenarios.

Comment: the IDE gives 100% code coverage, but this is not about coverage it is about tests scenarios which code coverage tools don't report.

Comment: If you are using eclipse IDE, you can install eclemma plugin for code coverage. This will tell you whether you have missed any branch for this method/class.

Comment: Yes - include all scenarios to execute all code branches.  Include edge cases as you mentioned in the post.  And consider Test Driven Development, or at least near time TDD.  Write a **little** code and add a new unit test.  Repeat.  Refactor with reasonable confidence.  Code coverage will naturally be 100%.

Comment: Ok, then may be mutation testing is what you are looking for, have a look at http://pitest.org/ and there is also a plugin for this in eclipse and intellij. But bear in mind, mutation tests take longer than normal code coverage depending your selected configuration.

Comment: What about this, you can define a list and put some cases in it. Then loop through the list and run Junit test with assertEquals for each of your case.

Comment: Yes Abubakkar, pitest.org can be a good answer to my request, it is a powerful tool, i am implementing it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Pitest.org as suggested by @abubakkar is the answer to this request, the tool make mutation tests by changing the byte code of your class, thus, run your tests against all the possibilities for failures, bugs, uncovered...